# Mapbox show secondary/tertiary roads

Tags: mapbox

I want to show secondary/tertiary roads at a zoom level like 10 or 11. At that zoom level I only see the primary roads, I did try to style it with carto css, but its not working.

Thank you

```
[class='secondary'][zoom>=11] {
  line-color: red;
  line-dasharray: 2,1;
  line-width: 19.2;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the whole CartoCSS file?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

The mapbox-streets-v6 vector dataset that ships with Mapbox Studio Classic only has certain vector data layers at each zoom level. The waterway data does not appear in this dataset at any zoom lower than 8, which is why you can't style it at any other zoom level.

Fortunately, this data comes from OpenStreetMap, so you can add it as a custom source in Mapbox Studio Classic and style it along with the other data! There is even a guide on grabbing this data from OpenStreetMap with Overpass Turbo.